# Use previous interactive argument in initial value for the next parameter

Tags: emacs, elisp

I need to access the previously entered interactive argument so that I can use it as the initial value of the next argument. To clarify what I mean, consider an example function which renames buffers:

```
(defun my/rename-buffer (old-name new-name)
  (interactive (list (read-buffer "Buffer to rename: " (current-buffer) t)
                     (read-string "Rename buffer to: ")))
  ;; Implementation here.
)
```

How can I access the value which was entered for `old-name` so that I can use it as the initial value for the `new-name` prompt?

Let me explain in more detail. When we do `M-x my/example`, the user is prompted like so (assuming `*scratch*` is the current buffer):

```
Buffer to rename (default *scratch*):
Rename buffer to:
```

If the user accepts the default for the first prompt (`*scratch*`), I would like the second prompt to use `*scratch` as the initial value displayed for the user:

```
Rename buffer to: *scratch*
```

If the user has instead typed the name of a different buffer for the first prompt, say `another-buffer`, the second prompt should have `another-buffer` as the initial value:

```
Rename buffer to: another-buffer
```

So the second prompt should always use the value of the first parameter as the initial value for the second prompt.

Some notes for clarity:

- I am not interested in the specific example of `my/rename-buffer` since the standard `rename-buffer` works fine. It really is just an example.
- I am looking for a solution which does not involve using a string as the  *arg-descriptor*. I need to compose the solution with existing *arg-descriptor*s which are lists of expressions. I don't believe they can be re-implemented as strings, but even if they could be, I not interested in such a solution.
- I do not wish to show the last value as part of the read-only prompt string, but instead I wish to use it as the modifiable initial value which is shown after the prompt string.
- The user pressing <kbd>↑</kbd> to access the previous argument is not a solution because I do not want to require user interaction to get the last value. I may also (in the future or for different functions) wish to show a slightly modified version of the last value rather than displaying it verbatim. Such a solution would also not work if the prompts are of different types, since they would not have the same history.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`interactive`, when given a lisp form, simply evaluates that form to obtain a list. You can do *anything at all* in that form, provided that the eventual return value is an appropriate list of values for the function arguments.

```el
(defun my/rename-buffer (old-name new-name)
  (interactive
   (let* ((old (read-buffer "Buffer to rename: " (current-buffer) t))
          (new (read-string "Rename buffer to: " old)))
     (list old new)))
  ;; ...
  )
```

Comment: Thank you! Looking at the documentation now, it is clear on this point, but my brain simply could not think beyond using a "list literal" of the form `(list ...)`.